# Trying to make a single query out of these 2 queries

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to get the percentage of calls that fit the allowed time-frame to get answered. But due to one condition, having the call less than 30 seconds, I am having an issue getting it to work. I tried working out the 30 seconds condition in the Select statement but it did not work ( I kept getting 100% every time and after looking at the numbers individually, it was not possible.

```
Select date, count("speed of answer" < '00:00:30')/ count(calls) as SLA
From five9_data.calllog
Where "call type" = 'Inbound' and campaign in ('Eves Addiction', 'Brook and York') and "service level" = '1' and skill = 'Eves Sales V' 
Group By date
Order By date desc
Limit 5000
```

Here are the 2 queries in full:

```
Select date, count(calls) as Total
From five9_data.calllog
Where 
  "call type" = 'Inbound' 
  and campaign in ('Eves Addiction', 'Brook and York') 
  and "service level" = '1' 
  and skill = 'Eves Sales V'   
Group By date
Order By date desc
```

AND

```
Select date, count("speed of answer") as AnsweredInTime
From five9_data.calllog
Where 
  "call type" = 'Inbound' 
  and campaign in ('Eves Addiction', 'Brook and York') 
  and "service level" = '1' 
  and skill = 'Eves Sales V' 
  and "speed of answer" < '00:00:30'
Group By date
Order By date desc
```

It has the same data source so union did not work, and did not think Join would work.

End game I want to be able to make a query that allows the 2 queries above to work and finally divide AnsweredInTime by Total.

Comment: Integer division? Try converting the numerator to a decimal before dividing?

Comment: Correct, that might be ideal, though converting is a pain in the backside for a noob like me, let me give it a try.

Comment: You would only need to convert in that expression. I guess with integer division it generally truncates to 0 rather than round up to 1, but still worth looking into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend writing the query as:

```
Select date,
       count(*) as total_count,
       sum( ("speed of answer" < '00:00:30')::int ) as num_AnsweredInTime,
       avg( ("speed of answer" < '00:00:30')::int ) as ratio_AnsweredInTime
from five9_data.calllog
where "call type" = 'Inbound' and
      campaign in ('Eves Addiction', 'Brook and York') and
      "service level" = '1' and
      skill = 'Eves Sales V'
Group By date
Order By date desc
```

Comment: For the win... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The COUNT(exp) function will count the number of rows for which `exp` is not null -- it doesn't care about true or false. You can verify this by executing the command `select count(false)` (evaluates to 1) and `select count(NULL)` (evaluates to 0). So instead of

```
 count("speed of answer" < '00:00:30')
```

you could try either

```
 count(nullif("speed of answer" < '00:00:30', FALSE))
```

(if speed is < 00:30 this will NOT be null, and thus will be counted) or

```
 sum(case when "speed of answer" < '00:00:30' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Select date,
       count(*) as total_count,
       sum( ("speed of answer" < '00:00:30')::int ) as num_AnsweredInTime,
       avg( ("speed of answer" < '00:00:30')::int ) as ratio_AnsweredInTime
from five9_data.calllog
where "call type" = 'Inbound' and
      campaign in ('Eves Addiction', 'Brook and York') and
      "service level" = '1' and
      skill = 'Eves Sales V'
Group By date
Order By date desc